# Fopen problems in php

Tags: php, fopen

In PHP im creating a tool to open txt file with an integer in it, increment the number, save the number to a variable and then save and close the file. this is the code i have for it and it doesnt seem to work when i have it on my test server. Can anyone clue me in as to why this isnt working properly?

```
//opens pclnumber.txt to $handle, saves number to $number, Increments number in text file, saves and closes file
$handle = fopen("pclnumber.txt", "w+");
$number = fread($handle);
fwrite($handle, $number+1);
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Is there any errors being reported?

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is not a helpful expression. What does that mean? Do you get an error? Is the file written or not? Does the universe implode?

Comment: try with `$number = file_get_contents("pclnumber.txt");` and `file_put_contents("pclnumber.txt", $number++);`

Comment: I think you need to specify [how many bytes to read](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) from your file.  I assume the number in `pclnumber.txt` keeps coming out to `1`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, when i print $number it prints as 0 when the file holds a larger number, 1365 i believe. Also when I open the file the number hasnt been incremented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

over all you must set reading permission on your file, and than you can use the follow code:

```
$filename = "pclnumber.txt";

//read file content
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$number = fread($handle, sizeof($filename));
fclose($handle);

//update file content
$handleWrite = fopen($filename, "w+");
fwrite($handleWrite, $number+1);
fclose($handleWrite);
```

Bye,
Marco